# how to insert into database table with different data types using Java SQL

Tags: java, sql, database

I have a Java SQL question relative to the insert method. If I have a database with multiple tables, I want to write a single insert method that can insert a row of data into any selected table for any type of relational database. If some tables contain different data types, for examples (integer, date, varchar, and etc.). My codes:

```
public void insertData(String tablename, String... values)
        throws SQLException {

    Connection          con = null;
    PreparedStatement   prepStmt = null;

    if (values.length == 0) {

        throw new SQLException("Must supply values");
    }

    try{

        con = getConnection();

        String  sql = "insert into "+tablename+" values(";

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            sql += "?";
            if (i != values.length-1) sql += ",";
        }

        sql += ")";

        prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            prepStmt.setString(i, values[i]);
        }
        prepStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    finally {

        closeStatement(prepStmt);
        closeConnection(con);
    }
}
```

For example, use case:

> Table Teacher has int id, varchar(50) name, int age, text subject, int
>   classid;
>
> Table Student has int id, varchar(50) name, date dateofbirth, text
>   address;
>
> Table Class has int id, text subject;

If I use:

```
insertData(Teacher, new String[] {"10", "Cass", "32", "Math", "10222"});
```

Will that data insert into the table successfully? I heard the database is only using varchar. If that is the case, then I don't have to worry about the type. If the type is varchar, should I use prepStmt.setString()?

I need to support multiple different types of database, such like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle and others. Will that one insertData() method work for all different databases?

Comment: you tell us whether the code works or not

Comment: @HaifengZhang I think it should work, but I don't have a database to test the method yet. I will create one and test it later, but the most difficult part is that I won't know what exact types will be in the table. So I want to create a single method to be able to do the insert no mater what data types are in the selected table because I know PreparedStatement can do setInt setString setBoolean. I heard PreparedStatement is better to use for query execution.

Comment: But my actual question is not about testing my codes, I will change my question.

Comment: Just updated, thanks.

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database meta data can tell you the details of the table.

What you can do is using `DatabaseMetaData` to get the column names, types and size, then you can choose `PreparedStatement` corresponding setXXX methods:

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "mytable", null);  // table name is mytable
while (resultSet.next()) {
  String name = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
  String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME");
  int size = resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
}
```

Another way is using `ResultSetMetaData`but you have to query from the table to get the `ResultSet`

```
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount() ; // returns the number of columns
    for(int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++){
        rsmd.getColumnName(i); //get name
    }
```

After you get the table's information(column name, type...), then you can choose proper query to update the table

Comment: I think that is the answer to go, but I will use a database to test it before I accept it. You use COLUMN_NAME TYPE_NAME, are they standard for getting column name and type? I did post a different question regarding to get a list of tables for different types of database. I know Oracle is using a different sql query to get a list of user table than SQL Server.

Comment: read more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

Comment: Yeap, it is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your scenario will work only in case when you are passing value for every column, if there is any nullable column in your table and you don't want to insert value on that it will not work and will throw sql exception as you have to specify the column name too in insert statement but when in your case you can pass Object array instead of String array and then call the appropriate setXXX according to the class type of parameter which your can fine from getClass method.